# Does iOS Address Book store the time/date that a contact was added?

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm building an iOS app that lists the contacts in the device and displays them by the most recently added.  Does the contact app (or the AddressBook API) store the date that a contact was added?  If not, is there I way that I can list contacts by most recently added?

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for `kABPersonCreationDateProperty` documented [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AddressBook/Reference/ABPersonRef_iPhoneOS/Reference/reference.html).